# Prolog does not evalutate parenthesis

Tags: prolog, simplify

I am trying to make an expression simplifier in Prolog, but one part has me stuck.
What I want to happen is `simplify(x*(4*x),R).` evalutes to `simplify(x*4*x,R).` then the rest will work its magic. But I can't seem to remove the parens. Here is the evaluation code below

```
simplify(x,x).
simplify(C*x,C*x) :- atomic(C),number(C),C\==1,C\==0.
simplify(x*C*x,W):- atomic(C),number(C), simplify(C*x^2,W).
simplify(C*x^N,C*W) :- atomic(C),number(C),atomic(N),number(N), simplify(x^N,W).
simplify(x^1,x).
simplify(x^N,x^N) :- atomic(N),number(N),N \== 1.
simplify(U*(V),R2):-  simplify(U,U1),simplify(V,V1),simplify(U1*V1,R2).%why will it not return a paren less output
simplify(U*V,R2):-  simplify(U,U1),simplify(V,V1),simplify(U1*V1,R2).
```

Comment: Of interest: [PRESS: PRolog Equation Solving System](https://github.com/maths/PRESS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parenthesis are used to change a term interpretation in the presence of operators. Note that, for the Prolog parser, there's no distinction between `simplify(U*(V),R2)` and `simplify(U*V,R2)`:

```
| ?- write_canonical(simplify(U*(V),R2)).
simplify(*(_279,_280),_284)

yes
| ?-  write_canonical(simplify(U*V,R2)).
simplify(*(_279,_280),_284)

yes
```

Thus, the last two clauses have the same head; there's a single operator in the `U*(V)` term.

Now consider the goal `simplify(x*(4*x),R)`. The operator definition for `(*)/2` is:

```
| ?- current_op(Priority, Type, *).

Priority = 400
Type = yfx

yes
```

I.e. the operator is *left-associative*. This means that e.g. `a*b*c` is parsed as `*(*(a,b),c)`. Therefore:

```
| ?- write_canonical(simplify(x*(4*x),R)).
simplify(*(x,*(4,x)),_285)

yes
| ?- write_canonical(simplify(x*4*x,R)).  
simplify(*(*(x,4),x),_285)

yes
```

Comment: So is there a way to turn
`simplify(*(x,*(4,x)),_285)` to `simplify(*(*(x,4),x),_285)`?